# Parsing CSV string in ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing

I have the following string - it's not exactly comma separated but has the same effect as a csv dataset:

```
response = "Date;Amount;Account;User\n2014-12-01;12.01;abcxyz;user1\n2014-12-01;10.09;fine;user2\n\r\n\t\t\r\n"
```

I tried running the following to parse it:

```
CSV.parse(response, :col_sep => ";", :row_sep => :auto)
```

but I get the following error:

> CSV::MalformedCSVError: Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n

Any idea why this would be happening?

I also tried doing a `response.gsub!("\t", "")` to see if that was the issue, but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: I just noticed that the [CSV.new](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new) documentation mentions `:auto` as a supported value for `row_sep`, but not `col_sep`. Because it's picking up this whitespace, it stays there, and you get this error because the fields weren't quoted.

Comment: Sorry typed it backwards, but still getting the same error

Comment: I think it's because you swapped `row_sep` and `col_sep` without swapping the `;` and whitespace characters in `response`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got it work with the use of [`#strip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-strip) :

```
require 'csv'

response = "Date;Amount;Account;User\n2014-12-01;12.01;abcxyz;user1\n2014-12-01;10.09;fine;user2\n\r\n\t\t\r\n"

CSV.parse(response.strip, :col_sep => ';') do |row|
  p row
end
```

output :

```
arup$ ruby a.rb
["Date", "Amount", "Account", "User"]
["2014-12-01", "12.01", "abcxyz", "user1"]
["2014-12-01", "10.09", "fine", "user2"]
```

Comment: it's working well

Answer (score 6):

This will give you each row in an array.

```
CSV.parse( response.gsub( /[\r\t]/, '' ), col_sep: ";" )
=> [["Date", "Amount", "Account", "User"], ["2014-12-01", "12.01", "abcxyz", "user1"], ["2014-12-01", "10.09", "fine", "user2"], [], []]
```

Unless you want to merge all rows into a single line, you need to leave the `\n` for the parser to interpret as a new row.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to fix this is to replace any consecutive whitespace characters with a single newline before you parse the string. Then you can use the newline as your row separator, instead of setting it to `:auto`. This should make CSV parsing faster (since it takes more time for `:auto` to guess your delimiter), though performance is technically also negatively affected by the additional call to `gsub`.

```
CSV.parse(response.gsub(/\s+/, "\n"), col_sep: ';', row_sep: "\n")
```